Reached maximum depth for account resolution
I have an anchor program that handles a basic multiplayer game between two players. On testing the startGame instruction, I get no error
But when I try to implement in my frontend, I get the error: Reached Maximum Depth for account resolution..... here's my tests implementation below followed by the :
  // Player 1 commits hash
  const gameId = new anchor.BN(1234);
  const wagerAmt = new anchor.BN(200);

  // Only the first 6 elements matter, the others are to be randomly generated to increase hash complexity
  // playerOneGuess.slice(0,3) represent player 1 keeper decisions. They are keeper
  // playerOneGuess.slice(3,6) reprersent player 1 shot taker decision. They are penalty taker
  // Points for any saves made
  const inputHash = generateHash(
    playerOneKP.publicKey.toString(),
    playerOneGuess
  );

  console.log(`input hash: ${Array.from(inputHash)}`)

  const ix = await playerOneProgram.methods
    .startGame(gameId, wagerAmt, Array.from(inputHash))
    .accountsPartial({
      mintAcct: mintPubkey,
    })
    .signers([playerOneKP])
    .instruction();
  const tx = new Transaction();
  tx.add(ix);

  const _txhash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [
    playerOneKP,
  ]);
  console.log(`P1 Started ${_txhash}!`);
  console.log(
    "P1 guessed (first 3 for keeper)(last 3 for shooter)",
    playerOneGuess.slice(0, 6)
  );
});

My frontend Implementation:
export const handleStartGame = async (
    wallet: ReturnType<typeof useAnchorWallet>,
    { connection }: ReturnType<typeof useConnection>,
    gameProgram: anchor.Program<Scorer>, //anchor program being referenced 
    mintPubKey: anchor.web3.PublicKey, //identifier for the public key of the mint account for token wagered(contract address)
    playerOneGuess: number[], //an array of player one guesses
    setGameStarted: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>,
    wagerAmt: number,
) => {
    // const {connection} = useConnection();
    if (!wallet) {
        alert("please connect a wallet to interact with the game")
        return;
    }
    // try {
        let gameId: anchor.BN;
        gameId = generateUniqueGameId(wallet);
        console.log(`gameId:${gameId}`)
        const wagerAmtBN = new anchor.BN(wagerAmt);

        
        //hashing player's guesses
        const inputHash = generateHash(
            wallet.publicKey.toString(),
            playerOneGuess
        )
        
        console.log(`player one guess: ${ Array.from(inputHash)}`)
        //fetching PDA of the game account
        
        const [gameAccount, gameAccountBump] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [mintPubKey.toBuffer(), gameId.toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8)],
            gameProgram.programId,
        )
        console.log("working")

        const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, wallet as any, {});
        console.log(provider)
        anchor.setProvider(provider)
        // const program = new gameProgram(idl as unknown as Scorer, provider );
        console.log(`mintpubkey: ${anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId}`)

        const txHash = await gameProgram.methods
        .startGame(gameId, wagerAmtBN, Array.from(Buffer.from(inputHash, 'hex')))
        .accountsPartial({
            mintAcct: mintPubKey,
            gameAccount: gameAccount,
            signer: wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc();

        await confirmTx(txHash, connection)
        console.log('Transaction confirmed:', txHash);
        setGameStarted(true);
        alert("A game session has started");
        
    // } catch (error) {
    //     console.error(`failed to start game: ${error}`)
    //     alert("an error occured when starting the game")
    // }

    setGameStarted(true)
    alert ("place holder for game start logic\n A game Session has started") //placeholder for start game logic
}


There is probably an account that is derived from another account in your accounts. You can use .accountsStrict() and pass in all accounts and see if that fixes the issues and then try figure out which of the accounts is causing the problem.
The problem is cause by anchor trying to resolve your accounts automatically for you if you use accounts() and accountsPartial() then there may be some accounts it can not resolve so you need to pass them in manually.
